# Downgrading Wordpress to previous version

Tags: wordpress

I was using version 3.4.2 with CKEditor 3.6.3 and everything was working fine, but WP was automatically updated to version 3.4.5 and now CKEditor doesn't work and with the default editor new posts are not formatted as expected.

Does anybody know a safe method to downgrade the version to 3.4.2 again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Two things: 1) WP never gets "automatically" updated. You can only start a WP update by clicking on "Update" in the admin... 2) I strongly, strongly recommend finding solutions to adapt to WP latest release and keeping up to date with the latest version of WP. Managing old versions of WP is way more trouble than finding the solution to whatever difficulty might arise with new releases. I unfortunately had experience with an old site: when WP is not up to date, you soon start bumping into all sort of problems when trying to maintain it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That would be the optimum solution but at this moment we can't afford to have dozens of poorly formatted posts. This is a temporary solution anyway, while we modify the code or get another suitable editor to replace CKEditor.

Comment: OK, good luck for all that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, but this one will downgrade all wp files including those in the root directory. At some point WP can modify those files so it is safest to include them.

This procedure will work only when the core WP files have not been modified (By you), there shouldn't though.

1. Make a backup of your site, just in case.
2. Save all files in the root directory that don't belong to WP (Icons, error pages, etc.).
3. Save the file `wp-config.php` in the root directory.
4. Save the complete `themes/`directory
5. Save the complete `plugins/` directory
6. Download the 3.4.2 version in case you don't have it.
7. Unzip it in the WP directory making sure the existent files are replaced.
8. Restore all saved files to the original directories and the `themes/` and `plugins/` directories.

The first time WP will ask for authorization to update the database. Select YES.

Everything should be the same except the version. Files in  `/wp-content/uploads/` will be the same.

I am not sure WP has automatic updates, I don't think so, but in case there are, **disable them.**

Comment: I kind of like your method better but what about some additional sub directories we have in wp-contents/themes/, will those be erased? There is no `theme` directory I guess you meant `themes`

Comment: Yes, I meant `themes/`. Sorry, It is corrected. Regarding your question, nothing is erased except the WP files. Other files or directories remain the same.

Comment: I already made a backup so I'll try your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Worked! No problems. Thanks.

Comment: Just a bonus tip (in case someone doesn't know it yet :) ) - you can download an installation of WP without the wp-content directory(this is what WP uses when it's updating itself), by going to `http://wordpress.org/wordpress-{tag}-no-content.zip` - where `{tag}` is the specific release that you're aiming for - for instance `3.4.2`. I'm not sure if that will work for all versions, but I just checked with 3.4.2 and yesterday I download 3.5 this way :)

Comment: Good tip! No content directory but all files in root except `wp-config.php` so it's perfect for downgrading too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The given answer didn't work for me downgrading from 3.6 to 3.5.2 but I was able to figure out a way that did work:

1. Export the site.
2. Make a copy of the Wordpress directory. Don't move it, just copy it.
3. Download the previous version.
4. Unzip the previous version into the Wordpress directory, replacing
   existing files.
   (This should keep the permissions identical. If you move the directory and create a new one your permissions might be wrong.)
5. Copy the themes/ and plugins/ directories from your backup to the wp-content directory.
6. There shouldn't be a wp-config.php file so just copy your backup to the Wordpress directory.
7. Try to open your site. 
   If it works you're probably good to go, if not continue with the following steps
8. Open the wp-config.php file on the server and change $table_prefix.
   e.g. $table_prefix  = 'wp2_';
9. Import the previous version's export file.
   Hopefully this works, if not you'll need to figure out what tables have changed and what you'll need to change in the export file to make it match the old database. You can do an export of your current, older version to see what changed. After you add some content of course.

Answer (score -1):

There is now a plugin for downgrading WordPress. Simply use it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/

Comment: It is good form to disclose your affiliation if you link to something, in this case to what I assume is a plugin you wrote.